# map reduce taking very long time to reduce 26 records

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Here's what I'm doing:

```
mongos> db.campaign_raw_data_459_imp.count()
21800002
mongos> db.campaign_raw_data_459_imp.find({ts:1350585328}).count()
26
mongos>  map = function () { emit(this.cookie, 1);}
function () {
  emit(this.cookie, 1);
}
mongos>  reduce = function (key, values) {return 1;}
function (key, values) {
  return 1;
}
mongos> 
mongos> db.campaign_raw_data_459_imp.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: { replace : "garbage"}}, query={ts:1350585328})
//This is hanging and taking forever, over 10 minutes now
```

There are 21m documents in this collection.  And, for a given timestamp (`ts`=1350585328), there are 26 records.  The goal here is to count how many unique cookies are in the matched records.  So it should find all the match documents, 26 of them.  And then drop them in buckets based on cookie, and then count the buckets.  I would presume that it would do the find, based on the query, FIRST, and then do a map/reduce with those returned values.  If that's the case, the size of the collection shouldn't matter at all.  It did the `count()` in the second line in a blink of the eye.

I have this indexed on `ts` and `cookie`, and I have a three shard setup with three replica sets.  My collection is sharded on three nodes, and each shard is a replica set with 3 members.

Why is this taking so long?  For prod, I'm going to open up ts to be a range (the last hour, perhaps), so it will have many many more matched documents than just 26.

Answer (score 1):

The `mapReduce` call parameters should look like this instead (all options in a single object):

```js
db.campaign_raw_data_459_imp.mapReduce(map, reduce, 
    {out: { replace : "garbage"}, query: {ts:1350585328}})
```

Comment: I'm using the pymongo driver, according to the documentation, you don't group it all together for pymongo  http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/examples/map_reduce.html#advanced-map-reduce

Comment: @Landon OK, but isn't your example code using the mongo shell?  Everything would look a bit different with pymongo.

Comment: yes, my example code is in the mongo shell.  I craft my code there and then copy it to my drivers.  Yes, technically different drivers perform differently, but I am experiencing the exact same time wait for the pymongo driver

Comment: @Landon You can't directly copy the parameters as the syntax is different between the shell and pymongo. Does the code in my answer run just as slow when you run it in the shell?

Comment: Yes, it is faster, but it still takes a couple seconds to do, this doesn't help my pymongo process, however

Comment: @Landon It would help if you posted your pymongo code if you that's what you want help with.